# what is the proper syntax to present data retrieved by meteor inside a callback function?

Tags: javascript, meteor

In y meteor app, I need to retrieve data from MongoDB, and then make that data available to various charting functions within Template.chart.rendered.
Currently, my (incorrectly structured code looks like this:

```
Template.chart.rendered = function () {
    var yelp_data = Yelp.find().fetch();
    ...
    var ndx = crossfilter(yelp_data);
}
```

This structure does not allow my code to wait until the data is retrieved, and then provide that data within a context of a callback.
What is the proper syntax for retrieving the data, and wrapping all subsequent processing within a callback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wait for the subscription to ensure that all of the data is present.  [Template Docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/Blaze-TemplateInstance-subscribe)

```
Template.chart.onRendered(function () {
 var template = this;

 template.subscribe('yelp', function () {  // Wait for the data to load using the callback
     yelp_data = Yelp.find().fetch();
     var ndx = crossfilter(yelp_data)
 });
});
```